# Localhost 8080 php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

Can someone please help me.
I'm new to creating docker containers. I tried to run `docker compose up` on my first laravel project and while the adminer port 8080 is working mysql mariadb is not. there is an [arm64 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3AdW.png)

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.8.3
    # Uncomment below when on Mac M1
    platform: linux/arm64/v8
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

So when I logged in my localhost database it throws an error like this:
[php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWuVk.png)

Comment: The arm64 mark is not tell an error, just a warning. Click the icon left of `mysql-1` can let you see the container logs, there must have some crash info.

Comment: Curious question, why still on [10.8.3](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes-mariadb-108-series/) rather than a later version?

Answer (score 1):

I made it work with the help of my friend.
My `manager-osx XAMPP` was running in the background that's why mysql mariaDB on docker won't start.

Also, I forgot to change the server name on my localhost. Instead of `db` it should be `mysql`